# Content for second div is not being alerted using $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my full code:

```
<input id="storecipient">
<div class="hidbdsp">
    <div class="hidname">tomato</div>
    <div class="hidname">orange</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#storecipient").on('input', function() {  
    var thisFstchar = $(this).val();
    var name = $(this).siblings(".hidbdsp").children(".hidname").html();
    if (thisFstchar.charAt(0) == name.charAt(0)) {
        alert(name);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

What my js code does is alerts the full word that contains the first letter of the word typed on the input. So when the letter "t" is typed, the word "tomato" shows up, but when "o" is typed on the input, "orange" does not show up. Even though both "orange" and "tomato" have the same class ".hidname", the $(this) selector only will select tomato but skips over orange. Why is this?

Comment: [`.html`](https://api.jquery.com/html/): _“Description: Get the HTML contents of the **first element** in the set of matched elements.”_

Comment: @SebastianSimon So instead of html(), which should I use in replace of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#storecipient").on('input', function() {
        var thisFstchar = $(this).val();
        $(this).siblings(".hidbdsp").children(".hidname").each(function() {
            var name = $(this).html();
            if (thisFstchar.charAt(0) == name.charAt(0)) {
                alert(name);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

```html
<input id="storecipient">
<div class="hidbdsp">
    <div class="hidname">tomato</div>
    <div class="hidname">orange</div>
</div>
  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know each functions could be appended to chains. This worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Thank you. Please accept the answer if it works for you :)

Answer (score 1):

As @misner3456 stated, [`jQuery.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) returns the HTML of the first matched element only. To get the HTML for all of the matched elements, try something like looping over all of the classes and appending each element's HTML to a string. For example:

```
let html;

$(".hidname").each(function() {
   html += $(this).html();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor to directly iterate `$(".hidbdsp .hidname").each()` rather than finding the sibling.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#storecipient").on('keyup', function() {
    var thisFstchar = $(this).val();
    $(".hidbdsp .hidname").each(function() {
      var name = $(this).html();
      if (thisFstchar.charAt(0) == name.charAt(0)) {
        alert(name);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<input id="storecipient">
<div class="hidbdsp">
  <div class="hidname">tomato</div>
  <div class="hidname">orange</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all children and descendant:

```
$('.hidbdsp *')
```

To get only direct children:

```
$('.hidbdsp > *')
```

.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="storecipient">
<div class="hidbdsp">
    <div class="hidname">tomato</div>
    <div class="hidname">orange</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#storecipient").on('input', function() {
        var thisFstchar = $(this).val();
         $('.hidbdsp *').each(function() {
            var name = $(this).html();
            if (thisFstchar.charAt(0) == name.charAt(0)) {
                alert(name);
            }
        });

    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```